# AWS Redshift UDF using pandas to normalize JSON

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, user-defined-functions

I've got a multi level JSON which I am trying to unnest in Redshift using UDF.

Reading [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-python-language-support.html) I can see we can use pandas in python UDF. My script is pretty simple. However, when I use it in Select statement I am getting 'SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function normalize_json("unknown") does not exist'.

Any guidance?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION normaliza_json(txt text)
RETURNS varchar(max)
IMMUTABLE
LANGUAGE plpythonu
AS $$
import pandas as pd

def normaliza_json(txt):
    return pd.json_normalize(txt)
$$;
```

Comment: why do you make a function when you don't need it

Comment: also you don't call your function

Comment: How else can I normalize a JSON object? Don't I need a function?

Comment: i am unsure if you can load pandas at all

Comment: But it says online Pandas comes as part of Amazon Redshift implementation. Am I misunderstanding something?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-python-language-support.html#udf-importing-custom-python-library-modules:~:text=In%20addition%20to%20the%20Python%20Standard%20Library%2C%20the%20following%20modules%20are%20part%20of%20the%20Amazon%20Redshift%20implementation%3A

Comment: your error says that pandas has no json_normalise on board

Comment: you could test if other functions work

Comment: Your function is named `normalizA_json` but you call `normalizE_json`.